# 500 server error (connection reset), JS file won't load

Tags: javascript, apache, shared-hosting, internal-server-error

**My Website: iansvoboda.com**

This JS file I am loading doesn't load properly for some reason. This randomly cropped up at some point in the last week or so and I haven't actually made any changes between now and then.

```
www.iansvoboda.com/js/app.min.js
```

My console indicates that this is due to a `500 internal server error: ERR_CONNECTION RESET`

I did some research and according to my server logs I saw an entry that stood out:

```
[Mon Jul 14 11:09:43 2014][debug] core.c(3118): [client 85.247.10.199] redirected from r->uri = /js/app.min.js, referer: http://iansvoboda.com/
[Mon Jul 14 11:11:11 2014][error] [client 180.76.6.58] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

Can anyone provide a suggestion for how to resolve? If you all need more info, just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Dig into your server configuration. Your logs say

> Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

This will tell you where the redirects are going, and you can spot the ones that can be removed (nobody needs more than 10 redirects — even your logs say "probable configuration error"). This will depend on your website's needs.

If nothing else, raise the `LimitInternalRecursion` to a value that prevents the error — but note that if it's caused by an internal loop, this won't help.

Comment: Thanks for the post. I'm not really sure how to actually do this, any advice?